# USB pyserial does not work on RPi3.

Tags: pi-3, usb, serial

Suggested /dev/serial0 does not exist in /dev. What tty works? What else needs to be done to make link work?

Comment: Surely there are some tutorials online?

Comment: [How-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697)

Comment: I find that when connected to Arduino Nanos and most Unos it is usually /dev/ttyUSB0,   Other Unos show up at /dev/ttyACM0.  When I get it wrong the IDE will generally suggest one that works.

Answer (score 1):

I've setup serial modems fine using the Pi3 serial service

It's defaulted to `/dev/ttyAMA0`

Comment: I have tried /dev/ttyAMA0 and it doesn't work (for me) on the RPi3. Works fine with RPi2. Other posts say the same thing, but you say it works?! The addition of Bluetooth hardware  forced a change in the UART device AMA0. Need a new device. Suggested /ttySerial0 does not show up in my /dev direcctroy.

Comment: I have an RPI3 working fine with USB modem using serial device /dev/ttyAMA0 - make sure you have the number zero (0) not letter "O" on the end - I did that by mistake once. I can send AT commands and dial in. What type of device are you using?

Comment: I am not saying you haven't done it but it **DEFINITELY ISN'T** "defaulted to /dev/ttyAMA0", which is used for Bluetooth.

Comment: Are you using Raspbian Jessie? What is in your `/boot/config.txt`

Comment: Pipe ls /dev/tty* to files before and after plugging. diff the two files.